# Mocha testing Promises remains stuck in the process (locked)

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm using Mocha to test my Node.js code. This particular test is checking if some stub returns an Array of filled objects.
The test is good, the result returns filled as expected and everything is "green lighted". But when it was expected to Mocha finish its process, it remains stuck. The only way to finish it is by pressing Ctrl+C.

I tried three kinds of writing the test (as follows). In all of them the test passes, but keeps the process locked:

1) Using simple then/catch methods:

```
describe('#getAll()', function () {
    it('should return a list of objects', function (done) {
        orderRepository.getAll()
            .then((result) => {
                assert.isArray(result);
                done();
            })
            .catch((err) => { done(err); });
    });
});
```

2) Using new Mocha-ready Promise test:

```
describe('#getAll()', function () {
    it('should return a list of objects', function () {
        return orderRepository.getAll()
            .then((result) => {
                assert.isArray(result);
            });
    });
});
```

3) Using recomended approach with async/await:

```
describe('#getAll()', function () {
    it('should return a list of Order objects', async function () {
        var result = await orderRepository.getAll();
        assert.isArray(result);                
    });
});
```

Again: ALL THREE METHODS returns a green lighted test, but remains stuck in the mocha process.

I'm using Mocha and Chai as required modules.

I'd be glad if anyone could help me!

Comment: Do you have another tests? If you comment this test out, will the process terminate properly?

Comment: @dhilt ... If I comment or skip this test, everythings goes fine, without any lock.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all your 3 tests and they seem to work fine and exit fine.[image][image].

Answer (score 0):

you can try to put `process.exit()`

idk if is the best way but worked for me :)